# Select to different interface using Typescript with Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, select, projection

I'm using Mongoose with Typescript, and is curious how to properly change type when using `select`.

For simplicity, let's say I have a `User` model, which has a `name` field, and a `role` field, which also has a `name` field. I want to select a list containing the username and the rolename.

```js
interface IUserRole {
  username: string;
  rolename: string;
}

const users = await User.find({}).select({ username: '$name', rolename: '$role.name' }).exec() as unknown as IUserRole[];
```

Is there a way of letting typescript treat users as IUserRole, in a more clean way than using `as unkown as IUserRole[]`? I have not been able to find it in the Mongoose documentation.

Comment: `const users: IUserRole[]  = await User.find({}).select({ username: '$name', rolename: '$role.name' }).exec()`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately this won't work, since it will complain that you cannot cast User to IUserRole